# Why Linux server keep sending IGMP report packet?

Tags: linux, networking

I am trying to identify a problem reported by our network admins.

One of CentOS 6.8 server kept sending IGMP report packet on MGMT/OOB interface, following is what I captured using 'tcpdump'

```
# tcpdump -vvv -i eth0 igmp
    20:48:22.711222 IP (tos 0xc0, ttl 1, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto IGMP (2), length 40, options (RA))
        server1 > igmp.mcast.net: igmp v3 report, 1 group record(s) [gaddr 224.0.32.4 to_ex { }]
    20:48:26.653012 IP (tos 0xc0, ttl 1, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto IGMP (2), length 40, options (RA))
        server1 > igmp.mcast.net: igmp v3 report, 1 group record(s) [gaddr 224.0.32.4 to_ex { }]
    20:48:52.720071 IP (tos 0xc0, ttl 1, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto IGMP (2), length 40, options (RA))
        server1 > igmp.mcast.net: igmp v3 report, 1 group record(s) [gaddr 224.0.32.4 to_in { }]
    20:48:54.091070 IP (tos 0xc0, ttl 1, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto IGMP (2), length 40, options (RA))
        server1 > igmp.mcast.net: igmp v3 report, 1 group record(s) [gaddr 224.0.32.4 to_in { }]
```

Network admin says a Linux box should not send IGMP report packets but I have no idea how to identify the root cause.

'eth0' is the MGMT interface and no other services in listening on that IP.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: As `root` run `ss -ap | grep 224.0.32.4`. With a bit of luck this will identify the process that is working with that multicast address. The `Network admin` is wrong to say a linux box should not send IGMP report packets. Since you say this is the MGMT/OOB interface, can we assume that this has a BMC, and that is what is actually connected to this interface rather than the main cpus? If so then the BMC is almost certainly not running CentOS, and the `ss` command will not show anything as it is being run on the wrong cpu.

Comment: @icarus What is BMC? `ss -aup4 | grep 224.0.32` did give me a PID. thanks for your advice.

Comment: Baseboard management controller -  see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface which allows you remote control of the server including power control and remote console access. From the process id you probably can deduce what is doing multicast.